# ZeroMQ master slave two way communication

Tags: zeromq

I want to create a networked architecture where a master process is connected with some slave processes and exchange messages in this way:

[image: schema]

Every slave should be able to send a message to the master. The master should be able to send a message to every subset of connected slaves.

i.e.

- Master sends a message to Slave 1
- Master sends a message to Slave 2 and Slave 3
- Master sends a message to all Slaves
- Slave 1 send a message to Master

These messages could have answers, but this can be handled at an higher level if there's not a dedicated way of doing this with ZeroMQ.

**This should work using only one port.**

With plain sockets I could make the Master bind on a port, accept connections, spawn a thread for every slave to handle incoming data and use the single connection to contact the single slave.

Since this architecture will use message-based communication, I think that ZeroMQ is the proper tool to implement it, but browsing the doc i can't find a way do that.

I'm going to write this in python, but the problem should be language agnostic.

Comment: Some questions : Are all slaves the same? Will slaves come and go? When sending to multiple slaves do you want to send to N specific slaves or just any N slaves?

Comment: @David the slaves won't come and go, the system should be really stable. Once the slaves are spawned, they should stay alive forever. I want to be able to send to N *specific* slaves. Define "the same"

Comment: By 'same' I meant same binary/script run multiple times, but thinking about it further this doesn't matter.

Comment: @David if it would have matter, computer programming would be a pretty lousy discipline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only using one port I think its best to use Dealer/Router :

- Master would be a `Router` socket
- Slave would be a `Dealer` socket
- When slaves start send an 'I'm here message' to the master which should store identity (first frame received) in a list of known slaves.

The master then sends to a slave by prepending the identity and an empty frame to the message. (You can only send to one client at a time with a router socket, but trivial to write a function to take a message and a list of slave identities and send to each in turn.)

The identities of the slaves can either be set by you, using the setsockopt call on the Dealer sockets, or ZeroMQ will auto assign unique ones if you don't.